# error: wrong #args: should be " proc name "

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

This is code script in gui.tcl:

```
label .login.nickLabel -text "User:"
entry .login.nick
label .login.hostLabel -text "Host:"
entry .login.host
chat::logic::login [.login.host get] [.login.nick get]
```

and this is code in logic.tcl:

```
proc chat::logic::login {hostName nickName} {
chat::model::getSock $hostName
...
}
```

and this is code in model.tcl:

```
proc chat::model:::getSock {hostName} {
variable sock
set sock [socket $hostName 9988]
fconfigure $sock -buffering line
return $sock
}
```

When I run the code, it reports an error: wrong # args: should be "chat::model::getSock hostName"

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure this is the error you get? `.login.host get` should be returning a string, and `chat::logic::login [.login.host get]` thus will fail because `chat::logic::login` requires two arguments.

Comment: That is a part of code in gui.tcl:
label .login.nickLabel -text "User:"
entry .login.nick
label .login.hostLabel -text "Host:"
entry .login.host
button .login.login -text "Login" -command {
chat::logic::login [login.host get] [.login.nick get]

Comment: Assuming `chat::model:::getSock` is a typo and is actually `chat::model::getSock`, then I cannot reproduce the error you are describing.

Comment: Can you maybe post the full error stack trace?

Comment: Just checking… you do have a space between the arguments to `proc`, and not nothing or a newline? Those sorts of syntactic mistakes (especially the second!) would lead to the kind of error message you report.